# insert/update/select value in user defined type of oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, user-defined-types

Create user defined type in oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  "CUSTOMER_NAME" AS OBJECT(FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20),LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20))
    /
```

used following code for data insertion in the table.

```
 INSERT INTO STAFF_INFO(STAFF_NAME,STAFF_PWD) VALUES (CUSTOMER_NAME('" & fname.Text & "','" & lname.Text & "'),'" & password.Text & "')"
```

but, when i'm trying

```
select STAFF_ID,STAFF_PWD,CUSTOMER_NAME(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) from staff_info
```

getting error **ORA-00904: "LAST_NAME": invalid identifier**

and when i'm trying this

```
select * from staff_info
```

then, i'm getting this error
**ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got ADS.CUSTOMER_NAME**

need help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an Oracle instance in front of me, but I've dealt with this before.  I recall I had to do something like:

```
select a.STAFF_ID,
       a.STAFF_PWD,
       a.STAFF_NAME.FIRST_NAME,
       a.STAFF_NAME.LAST_NAME
  from staff_info a;
```

Although the field `customer_name` probably shouldn't match the name of the type `customer_name`.

Comment: still showing the error `ORA-00904: "A"."CUSTOMER_NAME"."LAST_NAME": invalid identifier`

Comment: Is the name of your field the same as the name of your type?

Comment: yes, now it working. !! so, the same field name will be used in case of any operation like update/delete ...??

Comment: For some reason unknown to me, when you alias the table, it works that way. Definitely for select, and I'm pretty sure for updates and deletes.  But like I said, I don't have an instance in front of me to prove it out, so you'll have to do the honors.